# Uncaught ReferenceError: iphoneGallery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am using two different js since I am using two different layouts; one for desktop and one for iPhone.
Since for iPhone I need to reduce the cube size,
the cube size comes from the js,
but I am getting two different errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/24/

There two different js function one is:

```
$(document).ready(iphoneGallery.init);
$(document).ready(Gallery.init);
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: iphoneGallery is not defined

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
            location.reload();

            Gallery.setOptions({
                size: 78,
                lightbox: false,
                //animation:  'drop'
                //speed:      500,
                //closeOnEsc: true,
                //slideshow:  false,
                //slideshow_speed: 3000,
                //cube_speed: 1000
            });

        });
        
        
        $(window).bind('resize', function() {
            location.reload();

            iphoneGallery.setOptions({
                size: 78,
                lightbox: false,
                //animation:  'drop'
                //speed:      500,
                //closeOnEsc: true,
                //slideshow:  false,
                //slideshow_speed: 3000,
                //cube_speed: 1000
            });

        });
```

Comment: iphoneGallery is not defined anywhere. Missing some code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/24/ I am providing my fiddle too

Comment: yes it is, it is just defined inside an event listener. that is the problem.

Comment: can you update in the fiddle...its confusing http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/24/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By always calling both

```
$(document).ready(iphoneGallery.init);
$(document).ready(Gallery.init);
```

you always try to init iphoneGallery, even for not mobile browsers. You have to init just one of them, perhaps depending on screen width.

Also, your `iphoneGallery` definition is within an event listener, and that doesn't make any sense.

EDIT:

I tried to fix it, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/25/

Comment: thanks for your reply...instead of using user agent can we use this property window.innerWidth if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') >= 0) {
   $(document).ready(iphoneGallery.init);
  }